# 'Google Docs like ' functionality in python

Tags: python

What I have is a UI which allows users to enter info about, say toys.
Now the UI is accessible to multiple users at the same time and the info stored by the user gets stored in a file, which may cause accidental overwriting of toy info.
The file will contain info of multiple toys but same toy info can not show up again which is quite possible in multi user environment.
I am fairly new to web dev. and python too.
What should be my first steps to resolve this problem?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking AJAX would be a good place to start...

Comment: This is not the best place to ask, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq for guidelines on appropriate questions.

Comment: But this is a answerable question and practical too. Hence here.

Comment: According to the SO question flagging guidelines: "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." -- Questions like this are not concretely answerable.

Comment: SO is not here to do your research for you. There are plenty of other sites out there created with that purpose in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "popular" algorithm for allowing multiple people to safely operate on the same data is known as "operational transformation".

There are a couple of libraries that provide it, although I've never used any so I don't feel comfortable actually recommending any. But [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=operational+transformation+in+python) is a google search that should get you started. And, of course, there's [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).